# Active Admin Permitted Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Is there a way to tell whether I am in create or edit mode from inside the permit_params block of active admin? I'd like to merge created_by and updated_by when I'd creating a new record. When I'm editing an existing record I only want to merge updated_by.

Here's my code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Group do
  menu parent: "Groups", priority: 0

  permit_params do
    permitted = [:name, :description, :group_type_id, :owner_user_id]
    permitted.merge!(updated_by: current_admin_user)
    permitted
  end
```

I'd like to say something like:

```
permitted.merge!(created_by: current_admin_user) if new_record?
```

new_record? is an active admin method but it only seems to work in forms.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can merge it in the create and update action, too:

```
controller do
  def create
    params[:group].merge!(created_by: current_admin_user)
    create!
  end

  def update
    params[:group].merge!(updated_by: current_admin_user)
    update!
  end

end
```

Comment: This is how I'm doing it now and I think this is probably just as good as dealing with it in the permit_params. I did not know about the `create!` and `update!` but those are pretty cool.