# Pass current_admin_user.id into permit_params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In my application I have 2 models: `AdminUser`, which `has_many :announcements`, and `Announcement`, which `belongs_to :admin_user`. The `Announcement` table has `admin_user_id` column in a database.

In `app/admin/announcement.rb` I have:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Announcement do

 permit_params :title, :body, :admin_user_id

  controller do
    def new
      @announcement = Announcement.new
      @announcement.admin_user_id = current_admin_user.id
    end
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :title
      f.input :body, as: :ckeditor
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
```

Why my controller doesn't work? When I create an announcement through activeadmin, the column `admin_user_id` is empty. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added to a form: `f.input :admin_user_id, as: :hidden`, and now everything is working.

Comment: with this approach, smart users can easily create models with NON CURRENT USER IDs. I prefer to use this approach and control behaviour on the backend.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393691/active-admin-permitted-params